# How to get media player file play finished finished event in xamarin.forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

After file play finish I need to get event completed notification on how to implement in `xamarin.forms`

```
public void PlayAudioFile(String pathtowavfile)
        {
            try
            {
                var fileresouce = new Java.IO.File(pathtowavfile);
                if (fileresouce.Exists())
                {
                    player.Reset();
                    player.SetDataSource(pathtowavfile);
                    player.Prepare();

                    player.Completion += Player_Completion;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }

        }

        private void Player_Completion(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            player.SeekTo(length);
            player.Start();
        }
        public void Pause()
        {
            if (player.IsPlaying)
            {
                player.Pause();
                length = player.CurrentPosition;
            }
        }
```

Comment: sorry for format

Comment: There is already a `Player_Completion` event in your code. It doesn't work? What do you want?